# Vector pair ordering in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking to order a pair of vectors by the first inequal element.  Example:

```
[0, 1, 2] < [0, 2, 1]
```

because 0 == 0 so look at the next index, where 1 < 2.

Is there a simple way to do this in numpy?  Right now I am using this to find the difference between the "greater" and "lesser" vector, which leads to my first try, which is:

`(x - y) * np.sign((x - y)[np.nonzero(x - y)[0][0]])`

Comment: Do you really need to know how to compare the vectors that way for its own sake, or is that just a means to doing the difference calculation you mention at the end?

Comment: I am only using it in the difference calculation, but this is a fairly common method of comparing vectors so I was hoping there would be some Numpy function, or some commonly-known function, out there under a name that I haven't been able to think of.  But maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tuple: `(0,1,2)<(0,2,1)`. So a function like

```
def cmp(v1, v2): return tuple(v1) < tuple(v2)
```

should suffice ...

Answer (score 1):

[`np.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) is probably the most efficient way to do this:

```
import numpy as np

# an (N, k) array of N k-dimensional vectors
data = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 1]])

print data
# [[0 2 3]
#  [0 1 2]
#  [0 1 3]
#  [0 2 1]]

# lexsort assumes (k, N), so transpose data first. we also need to reverse the
# order of the columns, since lexsort sorts by the last column first
idx = np.lexsort(data[:, ::-1].T)

print data[idx]
# [[0 1 2]
#  [0 1 3]
#  [0 2 1]
#  [0 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would bet it will be way faster to do a simple loop through both arrays

```
def comparison(a,b):
    for i in xrange(len(a)): #assuming they have to be the same length
        if a[i] < b[i]:
            return True
        elif a[i] > b[i]:
            return False
    return False
```

For the 3 element vectors you posted the iteration is 7x faster on my machine.  For large enough stretches of identical initial elements the iteration will become slower but make sure that is the case before you go vectorizing.